# How to add the built from source boost library to qt creator on linux

Tags: c++, qt, boost, libraries, qmake

I compiled the boost library from the source using the scripts that came with the source (below the commands that I wrote)

> `/bootstrap.sh —prefix=/libs`

> `./b2 install`

After the build, 2 new directories appeared in the libs directory, include and lib, respectively.
[image]

Next, I registered the path to boost in the pro file qt creator

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += I-/libs/include/boost

LIBS += -L/libs/lib
```

In theory, I specified the path to both the headers (include / boost) and the binaries (lib), but nevertheless, when I try to compile the test code, I get a bunch of errors. How to correctly register a pro file if I want to connect asio, on Linux, where did I go wrong? (set of errors)

Comment: @Waqar, What file extension should you specify?

Comment: Do it like `LIBS += -L/libs/lib -lname` where `name` is `libname`. The format is `LIBS += -L<pathToLibrary> -l<libraryName>
`

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the library name in `LIBS`, only giving the path. Correct format is:

```
LIBS += -L<pathToLibrary> -l<libraryName>
```

Moreover `INCLUDEPATH` syntax is also incorrect. There's no need for `I-`.

```
INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/library
# e.g
INCLUDEPATH += libs/include/boost
```

And btw you don't need to link to anything if you are using asio only, since as far as I remember, Asio is header only so only include path will be necessary.

Comment: What format should the title be in? In the lib directory, files with the .o and .so extensions

Comment: no extension at all. just the name without `lib`. If it is `libxxx`, you only need to write `-lxxx`

Comment: eg LIBS += -L/libs/lib -llibboost_regex ?

Comment: Without 'lib'. Just `-lboost_regex`

Comment: @Waqar `asio` itself is header only but it relies on boost `system`, which isn't. So `-lboost-system` is also required.